# Wait for Firestore queries to complete

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to run multiple queries in firestore and want to wait for them to all complete before executing the next code. I've read up on several possible avenues but I have yet to find a good Android example.

```java
public HashMap<String,Boolean> multipleQueries(String collection, String field, final ArrayList<String> criteria) {

HashMap<String,Boolean> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < criteria.size(); i++){
    final int index = i;
    db.collection(collection).whereEqualTo(field,criteria.get(i)).limit(1)
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
         if(task.getResult().size() != 0 ){
           resultMap.put(criteria.get(index),true);
         } else {
             resultMap.put(criteria.get(index),false);
          }
    } else {
        resultMap.put(criteria.get(index),false);

    }

    }

     });
   }
   return resultMap;

}
```

Comment: If you'll be having more than 3 queries, I'd recommend restructuring your database in a way that you can reduce this number of queries. If that's not the case, this should be fine... In Android, the ideal way to wait for an asynchronous task to complete is to use [Coroutines](https://dev.to/rosariopfernandes/using-kotlin-extension-functions-and-coroutines-with-firebase-j0k#kotlin-coroutines), but these are only available in Kotlin. I'm currently not aware of any java equivalent to these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `get()` returns a `Task`, you can use [`Tasks.whenAll(...)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks?utm_campaign=Firebase_culture_education_general_en_10-04-16&utm_medium=blog&utm_source=Firebase#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)).

But you won't be able to return a `List` from this function, since all data is asynchronously loaded. The best you can do is return the result from `Task.whenAll(...)`, which is itself a `Task`. See Doug Stevenson's great article on becoming a task master: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html

Comment: I've been able to make multiple Tasks and add them to one Task using the whenAll(...) method but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get the individual query results. I'm querying for existence of a document so even if the doc doesn't exist it the query is still successful in finding that answer. Is there any way to access the results for the individual queries? Can I perhaps have a onSuccess listener for the individual queries to check the data there and if no document was found have that task throw something that would emulate a failure?

Comment: You can keep a reference to all individual tasks, or use `whenAllComplete` or `whenAllSuccess`.